# Get internet rx tx octet count from arbitrary router with SNMP enabled

Tags: linux, snmp, mib

Is it a reliable way to get internet traffic from router using following script:

```bash
ROUTER_IP=$(ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
WAN_PORT_INDEX=$(snmpget -L n -O qv -v2c -c public -m ALL $ROUTER_IP RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.0.0.0.0)
BYTES_IN=snmpget -c public -v2c  192.168.51.1 IF-MIB::ifInOctets.${WAN_PORT_INDEX}
BYTES_OUT=snmpget -c public -v2c  192.168.51.1 IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.${WAN_PORT_INDEX}
```

I've checked Mikrotik routers and an old cisco router with SNMP enabled `RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.0.0.0.0` points to the WAN interface. Is that by accident or this is by design?

Comment: Not necessarily. The OID refers to the interface index for the default route in the IP routing table of a network device, which could be a router, switch, or even a computer with routing capabilities. Whether this maps to the WAN (Wide Area Network) interface on a typical router depends on the specific network configuration.

In many common network setups, especially in home or small office environments, the default route usually points towards the internet, which is often accessible via the WAN interface. In such cases, this  may indeed correspond to the WAN interface.